# How to tell EF to put my model into multiple tables to prevent redundancy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF to store a many-many relationship in such a way that it prevents redundancy by creating a third table. However, from my OO point of view this  third table doesn't really exist, so I do not want to have a Model for it. Please consider the following set-up.

```
public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Inhabitants { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Structure> Structures { get; set; }
}

public class Structure
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

I would like EF to generate the following, with `StructureInfo` as third table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City] (
    [ID]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Inhabitants] INT            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Structure] (
    [ID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StructureInfo] (
    [ID]           INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Location]     INT NOT NULL,
    [City_ID]      INT NULL,
    [Structure_ID] INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StructureInfo_dbo.City_City_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([City_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[City] ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StructureInfo_dbo.Structure_Structure_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([Structure_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Structure] ([ID])
);
```

From a database point of view this seems like the right thing to do, since `Location` is different per city, yet the concept `Structure` might appear in many cities. `Location` is a property of the relationship between the entity `City` and the entity `Structure` and should therefore be in a separate table. However, from the OO point of view this separate table serves no purpose and `Location` is a property of the particular instance of `Structure`. I have no interest in a Model that describes the relationship.

How can I tell EF to create the tables such as I describe above from just the two Models that I created and such that EF makes the INNER JOINs where required when using the information?

Answer (score 1):

If Location is a **property of the relationship**, you can't avoid having a relationship object.

EF will create a "non existing in the object world" table to manage n to n relationship, if it keeps only the "relation", but if the relationship has specific properties, than the relationship must exist as a type (and as a table)

Even in the object world, it's not a property of an instance of structure, cause, as you say, a structure could appear in many cities (so one instance of structure could be related to many instances of city : so that instance of structure can't have differenct value for Location).

So you should  have something like

```
public class City {
    public virtual ICollection<CityStructure> CityStructures {get;set;}
}

public class Structure {
    public virtual ICollection<CityStructure> CityStrucutres {get;set;}
}

public class CityStructure {
    public int Location {get;set;}
    public virtual City City {get;set;}
    public virtual Structure Structure {get;set;}
}
```

**Edit**

And if you had not a property related to the relationship, the relation table MUST be present, as you can't store a "collection" as a database field. You just don't need to mind in the object world.

Comment: +1 - I'd also add if you're reluctant to alter your object model to describe the relationship, then it's probably a sign you're not building a layered application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep associations. Satellite table is a common practice for mapping many-to-many. You don't need to get rid of this table.